# I am trying to connect the two tables with the help of a join, but it is not working in my SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to connect to tables with the help of join but it is not working in SQL.

Please guide me to the mistake I am making in this query.

```
select first_Name, salary, dept
from employees
inner join department on employees.dept = department.dept
```

I get an error

> Ambiguous column name 'dept'

but I don't know why...

I was trying to get the data from both the tables on the bases of dept.

Comment: Because the same column exists in both tables? You have to prefix the column with the table name.

Comment: Dale K means select first_Name, sallary, dept should be: select first_Name, sallary, employees.dept for example

Comment: Please mention the table to which the 'dept' column in the select statement belongs. For example: first_Name, sallary, employees.dept

Comment: Thank you so much. This has solved the query :-)

Answer (score 0):

You select `dept`, but the DBMS want to know whether you mean `employees.dept` or `department.dept`, despite them having the same value in your query.

It is good practise to qualify all columns with their table name when working with multiple tables:

```
select employees.first_Name, employees.salary, employees.dept
from employees
inner join department on employees.dept = department.dept;
```

(Which shows that the join to the department table is completely superfluous as yet.)

As the long table names can make queries harder to read, it is also good practice to use mnemonic table aliases:

```
select e.first_Name, e.salary, e.dept
from employees e
inner join department d on e.dept = d.dept;
```